# http-long polling and -streaming: send data on same connection?

Tags: http, streaming, request, long-integer, polling

Just another quick question of understanding here...
I'm wondering, while an HTTP request from a client is pending on the server when using long-polling or http-streaming, is it possible for the client to send data via the *same* connection or does the client have to create another connection for that, putting more load on the network and the server ?

I assume the latter, but I'm not sure. Stumbled accross this IETF doc here, but also could not find an answer there: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-loreto-http-bidirectional-07

Thanks for your help in advance, as always.

EDIT: To clarify my question a bit: I want to know wheather bi-directional communications between a server and a client is still possibla via one connection (while long polling or http steraming is in use), as with using somethng like webSocket. Overhead is irrelevant for this question btw.

Answer (score 0):

If a client and a server supports HTTP/1.1, they can use [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), which allows for issuing new requests regardless to the fact if other requests have been issued and are still waiting for responses. This works through the same single connection. The main requirement for such parallel requests is that they should be **idempotent**, that is they should not affect each other via possible changes in server state (data).

Comment: thanks for answering. OK so pipelinging enables the sending of multiple requests or responses in _one_ direction. I edited my question to clarify since I think I asked slightly the wrong thing...the question is: When using http long polling or -streaming, is bi-directional communications between a server and a client (still) possible? I know webSocket makes this possible, and http-streaming seems to work similarly, but I'm not sure about the bi-directional aspect.

Comment: As you actually asked about simultaneous steaming from and sending another data to a server (initialized by a client, I suppose), this is possible, though may be a matter of HTTP pipelining implementation in specific client/server pair. But it can not be a fully fledged bi-directional connection just because the server can not send requests to the client on its own.

Comment: so _without_ the use of HTTP-pipelining, long-polling and streaming does NOT enable fully bi-directional communication, did I get you right there?

Comment: I mean, _fully_ bi-directional communication is not possible neither with nor without HTTP-pipelining. From your original posting I thought you want to issue several requests from the client, so that they run in parallel. This is what HTTP-pipelining will allow. If you need fully bidirectional communication, use websockets - they are full-duplex.

Comment: k thanks for explaining - and yes, I asked the question in a wrong way before I edited it, sorry about that :)